# Sanitization of dynamic MySQL WHERE clause in PHP

Tags: php

I’ve built a MySQL WHERE clause for a SELECT query dynamically within a foreach loop. The `$_GET` data comes from a form containing numerous select lists each allowing multiple-selections.

For example if the following form data is submitted:

```
$_GET = Array (
  ['foo'] => Array ( [0] => a ) ,
  ['bar'] => Array ( [0] => b, [1] => c) ,
  ['foobar'] => Array ( [0] =>  '')
)
```

Using the processing code:

```
$whereinitialize = array();
$where = " ";
$whitelist = array ('foo', 'bar', 'foobar');
foreach ($_GET as $key => $values) {
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $whereinitialize[$key] = isset($whereinitialize[$key]) ? $whereinitialize[$key] : false;
    if (in_array($key, $whitelist)) {
      if ($value == "") {
        $whereinitialize[$key] = "1"." OR ";
      } else {
        $whereinitialize[$key] .= ("$key = '$value'")." OR ";
      }
    }
  }
}
foreach ($whereinitialize as $v) {
  $where .= "(".(rtrim($v, " OR ")).")"." AND ";
}
$where = rtrim($where, " AND ");
```

My WHERE clause (`$where`) then outputs:

```sql
(foo = 'a') AND (bar = 'b' OR bar = 'c') AND (1)
```

Functionally, this is working fine for my purposes, however I’ve read various posts suggesting that dynamic processing of superglobals is fraught with security issues. So my question is, given the use of a whitelist and escaping the data using mysql_real_escape_string, is the form processing dynamic code shown above likely to be more of a security risk than manually extracting and sanitizing each value individually as per standard practice? (i.e. `$foo = $_GET[‘foo’]` etc etc)

Comment: Because you have a whitelist for your keys and you are using real_escape_string on your values your code is secure

Comment: @chrislondon. Thanks. There seems to be a lot of hesitation out there about processing forms dynamically, for both security and code readability reasons. Perhaps things can easily slip between the gaps?

Comment: Yeah it's very easy for things to fall through the cracks.  The two big things are 1) don't put user data straight into queries without doing `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and 2) don't echo user data back to them on the page without doing `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you using PDO prepared statements.
Do not use mysql function any more, not only PDO has lot of more functionality over simple mysql, but also in newer versions of PHP mysql_* functions will be deprecated.

In PDO, your can use prepared statements and you would not need to wory about SQL injection,l because parameters which you want to pass to your database method in order to do sth with them in database will sanitize, escape and these kind of stuff for you and makes life much mroe easier.

Here is the link to PDO in php: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
and here is about prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you, l'll look into PDO immediately.